# Navigating a organizational hierarchy, how to represent the top?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working with hierarchal organization data.

```
public class Position
{
  public string PositionCode { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public Position ReportsToPosition { get; set; }
}
```

Each Position has a property pointing to the Position it reports to.  However, at the very top of the organization is the President, who doesn't report to a real Position.  In its place, I've created a derived class named PositionNone.

```
public class PositionNone : Position
{
    private static PositionNone _positionNone;
    public PositionNone()
        : base(positionCode: "None",
               title: "None",
               reportsToPosition: _positionNone){}
}
```

This code will build, but it doesn't feel right.

- we're using Nullable Reference Types and _positionNone is not initialized.
- since there should only ever need to be a single PositionNone, I'd like to mark it static and have it self-reference, `public static class PositionNone : Position`, but that is not allowed.

I want to keep the rich model hierarchy below the president, but need to figure out how to represent the very top.  I can deal with the possible infinite loop when walking up the hierarchy.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?  Am I completely off base? Do I need to head in a different direction?

Comment: Make it a static property of `Position`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/J58Bx7

Comment: Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.  I did this same approach with an Enumeration class, but didn't make the leap that I could use it for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make `PositionNone` a static property (or field) of `Position`. Something like:

```cs
public class Position
{
    public Position(string positionCode, string title, Position reportsTo)
    {
        PositionCode = positionCode;
        Title = title;
        ReportsToPosition = reportsTo;
    }

    public string PositionCode { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Position ReportsToPosition { get; set; }

    public static Position PositionNone => new Position(
        positionCode: "None", 
        title: "None", 
        reportsTo: Position.PositionNone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When someone has none to report to it means it is the president, do not be shy in using null even in a non-nullable environment.

Delete PositionNone and make ReportsToPosition explicitly nullable.